# How to end a twilio call prematurely

Tags: twilio

I want to use twilio to test our internal phone system, and make sure calls are routing as they should, since our provider is notoriously bad of notifying us to problems.

I'm can initiate a call from twilio, use the "gather" verb to record speech (to ensure we hit the right queue) and then hang up.  Everything works fine.  Except that the gather ends up taking over 2 minutes to listen to the whole message from our phone system, charging us for 8 15 second gather chunks.  I only need the first 15 seconds, but can't figure out how to hangup sooner.  Is there a simple way to limit calls to a specific time?

timeLimit, and timeout both don't apply here, since timeLimit only works inside of a dial verb, and timeout only works for pauses in speech during the gather.

Comment: Just to make it a bit more clear, I use the rest API to initiate the call with a URL parameter that when accessed returns just a generic "gather" response in TwiML.  I have to wait for that gather to gather all 2 minutes of speech.  Instead, I want it to gather for 15 seconds, send me the result, and hangup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps just set a timer in your code for 15 seconds or so and then use the [POST endpoint](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/modify-live-calls) at `/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Calls/{CallSid}` to cancel the call (using the `Status=Completed` parameter in order to cancel calls even if they are in progress).

Comment: I tried this, however I then didn't get the results of the gather.  Let me give this a try again, maybe it was a fluke.

Comment: Perhaps you could try using the [`partialResultCallback` URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-partialResultCallback) which will send you updates as they are translated. If you end the call prematurely the `action` URL will never get called.

Answer (score 0):

If you use their Ruby SDK, and you make a normal call (not a conference call) then you can use the `update` method:

```ruby
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)
# fetch all in-progress calls between the two numbers
client.calls.list(from:   '+11231231234',
                  to:     '+12312311234',
                  status: 'in-progress').each do |c| #it's supposed to be just one record, but you can play it safe
  c.update(status: 'completed')
end
```

- Updating the status to `completed` should hangup the call if in-progress.
- Updating the status to `canceled` should hangup the call if ringing/queued.

If you know for sure that the call is in-progress and you know the call sid, then you can use:

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)
in_progress_call = client.calls(call_sid).fetch
in_progress_call.update(status: 'completed') if in_progress_call.present?
```

There is some general information in [the official docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/modify-live-calls). Also snippets are available for the other SDKs.

You can find the [source code of the update method here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/blob/bd7bc2d35feb9f71128e476053a1ec9bddc026a6/lib/twilio-ruby/rest/api/v2010/account/call.rb#L393) for more details.